# Configuration Deployment to Linux Systems

Tags: linux, configuration-management, asset-management

I'm looking for a nice way to add / remote ips (and possibly interact with an asset inventory system to track where ips are), start / stop processes, download logs, and all around genearal system admin duties from one place.

It's okay if I require more than 1 program. That would still be better than having 50 million terminals open and trying to trace ip assignments etc on whiteboards.

I'd also like to know if anyone knows any good asset management programs.

Best Regards,
William

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/)

Comment: Puppet looks nice! I'm going to check it out.

Comment: Go in with eyes open, it does have a steep deployment curve. Just make sure to figure it out in your test environment.

Comment: I tried to up vote you, but I don't have enough rep on this side yet =(.

Comment: Puppet, definately. Been using it for a while and love it.

Answer (score 3):

Puppet + The [Foreman](http://theforeman.org/wiki/foreman/Screenshots) for inventory and provisioning.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to also have a look at cfengine.  It is far older then Puppet, but the agents are far more light-weight.  Same basic concepts as Puppet, as far as automation goes.

Comment: That's like saying OSX has the same basic concepts as a Commodore 64 because they both have a CLI.  cfengine is antiquated and has no place in a modern configuration management stack.

Comment: What's wrong with CFEngine these days? Is CFEngine 3 any better or closer to Puppet now?

Answer (score 0):

Along with Puppet which handles your pull based needs, you might want to look at something like [Mcollective](http://www.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/) or [Func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/) for when you need to push commands out to a group of servers (like aperiodic `apt-get upgrade`s)